# How to check subscription status in Flutter for GooglePlay and AppStore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I try to use Flutter's plugin called: in_app_purchase. It has some example of its usage: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart

I don't understand how to check subscription status: is it still active or not?

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer, I think maybe we have to handle it manually.

Comment: need the same info